# Deployment Commit Phase failed: Solr Indexer having documents excel

Tags: publishing, si4t

This is my SOLr storage config file.

```xml
<Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" Mode="http"
         DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8982/solr/tridion" 
         DocExtensions="xls">
```

My published page has download binary file excel. Because of that this got failed. If I remove that file and republish the page it works.

Error message received:

> Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failed, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-27017-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-27017-66560 because of Server at localhost:8982/solr/tridion returned non ok status:404, message:Not Found

### Update

Stacktrace:

```
com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPip‌elineExecutor.java:197) 
[cd_deployer.jar:na] at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecu‌tor.java:97) 
[cd_deployer.jar:na] at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecuto‌​r.java:61) 
[cd_deployer.jar:na] at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.j‌​ava:82) 
[cd_deployer.jar:na] at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:‌​175)
```

Excel version is Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet using the extension `.xls`.

On the Solr log side I didn't find any error message.

More Information From cd_extention.log
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Adding removeItemFromIndex: [REMOVE,tcm:24-7519-64,PAGE,defaultFile]
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SearchIndexProcessor - Trigger indexing for item: tcm:24-7519-64, action: REMOVE, storageId: defaultFile
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SearchIndexProcessor - Setting Publication Id to: 24
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - No Solr Url found for publication Id: 24. Trying to use the DefaultCoreUrl
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Default Url found. Using [http://localhost:8983/solr/tridion] to connect to.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Adding binaries to Solr.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SolrIndexDispatcher - Dispatching binary content to Solr.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 TRACE SolrIndexDispatcher - File created: C:\Windows\TEMP\Test_tcm24-13328.xls4748519690011597698xls
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 TRACE SolrIndexDispatcher - IOUtils is done writing binary content.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexDispatcher - Indexing binary with Id: binary:24-13328, and URL Path:/website/en/Images/Test_tcm24-13328.xls
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 INFO  SolrIndexer - Clearing out registers.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - Register currently contains:
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - tcm:0-41886-66560
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - Clearing register for transaction:tcm:0-41886-66560

Solr.log

DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.util.ServiceConfigurationError
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.util.ServiceConfigurationError from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded interface java.util.Iterator
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded interface java.util.Iterator from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator from WebAppClassLoader=1464174591@574587ff
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.util.NoSuchElementException
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.util.NoSuchElementException from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.AssertionError
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.AssertionError from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.Reader
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.Reader from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.InputStreamReader
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.InputStreamReader from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded interface java.util.Enumeration
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded interface java.util.Enumeration from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.BufferedReader
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.io.BufferedReader from null
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils from WebAppClassLoader=1464174591@574587ff
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.Error
DEBUG - 2014-01-22 16:58:02.855; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader; loaded class java.lang.Error from null

Comment: Can you provide: a) Any error logging on the Solr side, b) any error logging in the extensions log, c) The version of the Excel document you're trying to index?

Comment: Can you change your logging on the deployer side in logback.xml as explained here: https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/master/storage-extensions/conf/logback_example.xml . Then publish the Excel and post the error message here. :)

Comment: @user409 please respond to the comments by editing your question and adding additional information in there, that is a lot more readable and keeps the number of comments to a minimum.

Comment: Is it just one specific Excel file, or do all Excel files cause this problem?  Are you having issues with any other file type?  Does the Page successfully publish if you remove the SI4T Storage Extension?

Comment: @Jonathan Williams: Yes If I remove SI4T Storage Extension, it's getting success. or If I remove this xsl extension in this configuration it's getting success DocExtensions=""

Comment: @Velmurugan Is it just this one specific Excel file, or do all Excel files cause this problem?

Comment: @Jonathan Williams: I did tested with another excel file, still problem exist the same. I can able to see that page got published in file server, binary folder i can able to see that excel file got published. but status getting failed on publishing queue

Comment: More Information From Error cd_extenstion.log

2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Adding removeItemFromIndex: [REMOVE,tcm:24-7519-64,PAGE,defaultFile]
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SearchIndexProcessor - Trigger indexing for item: tcm:24-7519-64, action: REMOVE, storageId: defaultFile
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SearchIndexProcessor - Setting Publication Id to: 24
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - No Solr Url found for publication Id: 24. Trying to use the DefaultCoreUrl

Comment: 2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Default Url found. Using [http://localhost:8983/solr/tridion] to connect to.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexer - Adding binaries to Solr.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 DEBUG SolrIndexDispatcher - Dispatching binary content to Solr.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 TRACE SolrIndexDispatcher - File created: C:\Windows\TEMP\Test_tcm24-13328.xls4748519690011597698xls
2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 TRACE SolrIndexDispatcher - IOUtils is done writing binary content.

Comment: 2014-01-22 16:58:35,491 INFO  SolrIndexDispatcher - Indexing binary with Id: binary:24-13328, and URL Path:/website/en/Images/Test_tcm24-13328.xls
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 INFO  SolrIndexer - Clearing out registers.
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - Register currently contains:
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - tcm:0-41886-66560
2014-01-22 16:58:35,537 DEBUG FSSearchDAOFactory - Clearing register for transaction:tcm:0-41886-66560

Comment: Ok. I think I know where it goes wrong. Can you put your schema.xml in the start post please? It is probably missing some fields. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the lack of further information, I can only give generic troubeshooting hints.

**1. Solr Configuration for indexing binaries**

The most probably cause is that on the Solr side, you have not configured the data import handlers for indexing binaries properly. You need to ensure that all jar files which perform the imports are present in the **lib** directory of your Solr server. The most important jar files are: **apache-solr-cell-XXX.jar**, **tika-core-XXX.jar**, **tika-parsers-XXX.jar** and **poi-XXX.jar**. If either of these is not present, then indexing of binaries will fail. Additionally, you will need to have the import handlers configured in the `solrconfig.xml` file of the Solr Core you are trying to index to. You can find the jar files for a couple of much used configurations on the [Solr 101 Configuration](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101) page.

By default, SI4T comes with the following configuration:

```
<requestHandler 
    name="/update/extract"     
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="uprefix">binary_</str>
    <str name="fmap.content">binary_content</str>
    <str name="fmap.title">BinaryEmbeddedTitle</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

**2. Corrupt binary file**

It could also be the case that the Excel file you are trying to index is corrupt somehow. Try to upload a new test Excel sheet into Tridion and see if it indexes. If that is the case, then you should probably re-upload the Excel file which fails.

**3. Unsupported file formats**

Although Solr does support a multitude of [binary file formats](http://tika.apache.org/1.3/formats.html) to index, it cannot index all formats. For instance, Microsoft Office documents prior to Microsoft Office version 97 cannot be indexed, because of the proprietary nature of that format. So - do ensure the Excel file is not actually in that format.

**4. Check your schema.xml**

Binary indexing requires to have the following fields (apart from the *id*, *pubdate* and *url* fields) present in your schema.xml:

```
    <!-- Binary extraction storage fields -->
    <field name="BinaryEmbeddedTitle"
        type="string"
        indexed="true"
        stored="true"
        multiValued="true" />
    <field name="binary_content" type="text_general"
        indexed="true"
        stored="true"
        multiValued="false" />
    <field name="fileType" type="string"
        indexed="true"  stored="true"
        multiValued="false" />
    <field name="fileSize" type="string"
        indexed="true"
        stored="true"
        multiValued="false" />
```

**Further hints**

If either of these hints cannot help solve the problem, [configure your log levels of your Solr server](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging). If properly configured, you will be able to see exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to configure your suggestion, where should i get this jar files

Comment: Read https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101 . Depending on your versions of Solr and Tridion you can select the right set of jar files if you don't already have them.